# Foreign key on two columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, erd, subtyping

For my school project i needed to create a database. This is my ERD.

[image: ERD]

In SQL i create the Category table:

```
CREATE table "Category" (
  "Id" NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
  "SubCategoryId" NUMBER(5) NULL,
  "Name" VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "Category_pk" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
);

ALTER TABLE "Category" ADD CONSTRAINT "Category_fk" FOREIGN KEY ("SubCategoryId") REFERENCES "Category" ("Id");
```

Product table

```
CREATE table "Product" (
  "Id" NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
  "CategoryId" NUMBER(5) NOT NULL, /* Category.Id or Category.SubCategoryId */
  "Name" VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL,
  "Brand" VARCHAR2(32),
  "Type" VARCHAR2(32),
  "Year" NUMBER(4),
  CONSTRAINT "Product_pk" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
);
```

The product table has a CategoryId (foreign key) on Category.Id, but the Product.CategoryId also needs a foreign key on Category.SubCategoryId.

Is this possible, or should i create an extra table called "SubCategory" and then add foreign keys to Category.Id and SubCategory.Id?

Comment: Why do you think that `Product` table needs a foreign key on `Category.SubCategory` ? `Product` table has reference on `Category` and `Category` itself has reference to `SubCategory`. I think that current `DDL` is ok if `product` has link on `category` but not on subcategory

Comment: SubCategory need a parent. But you can assign a product to a Category without an SubCategory.

So i need to assign a product to Category.Id or Category.SubCategoryId.

Comment: SubCatagory is category that has a parent, so you Product needs a link to a some Category no matter if it has parent or not, so current DDL is ok. Am i right?

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by DDL? Yes thats right, Product.Id needs a relation to Category.Id or Category.SubCategoryId

Comment: `DDL` is your `CREATE TABLE..` code. There is no such **entity** as `SubCategory`, there is only `Category`. `Product` must has link to some `Category` and it's no matter in what level of `Category` hierarchy it stands.

Comment: I think this will be more clear if you rename SubCategoryId to ParentCategoryId as Product belongs to a category that _may_ belong to a parent category.

Answer (score 1):

The foreign key reference belongs in the *Category* table not any other table.  This is clear from the E-R diagram.  You have even circled the appropriate link.

I would write the definition more like this:

```
CREATE table Category (
  CategoryId NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
  SubCategoryId NUMBER(5) NULL,
  Name VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT Category_pk PRIMARY KEY (CategoryId),
  CONSTRAINT fk_Category_SubCategory FOREIGN KEY (SubCategoryId) REFERENCES Category(CategoryId)
);
```

Notes:

- Don't use double quotes for table and column names.  They just make the code harder to write and to read.  As a corollary, don't use reserved words, spaces, or other bad characters in such names.
- I name the primary key of a table to include the table name.  That way, most foreign key columns have exactly the same name as primary key columns.
- I commend you for naming all the constraints, instead of just using `primary key` and `references` on the column definition line.